# Octave equivalent to matlab pretty

Tags: octave

Does anybody know the octave equivalent function to Matlab's pretty. I have tried the following

```
symbols
x = sym('x')
diff(sin(x)*cos(x),x)
pretty (ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried `pretty(ans)` in octave and it did not throw an error. Also, the answer output was not enhanced. I think the function pretty is automaticly called on the output in Octave.

Comment: *"error: help: the 'pretty' function belongs to the symbolic package from Octave Forge which seems to not be installed in your system."*

Comment: it seems that you need the `symbols` package

Comment: How do you install this? I can't find it and `pkg install symbols` results in `Couldn't resolve host name` error.